# Exporting table data in csv file using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have these requirements:

1. Export table data into a `.csv` file using a stored procedure
2. First row in the `.csv` file will be a custom header

Note: data in this row will not come from table. It will be a fixed header for all the `.csv` being generated.

Similar to something like this:

```
Latest price data:
product1;150;20150727
product2;180;20150727
product3;180;20150727
```

Comment: are you using sql server 2008, 2008R2 or 2012??? you tagged all of them which is not helpful.

Comment: You could do this by running xp_cmdshell + bcp and handle the header by copying it from a different file, but I don't think this is something you should be doing in a SQL Server procedure

Comment: Thanks #JamesZ for the response but I am looking some solution without using  xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `date` is a proper `datetime`column the following procedure will at least do the job for this table named `prodtbl`:

```
CREATE proc csvexp (@header as nvarchar(256)) AS
BEGIN
 SELECT csv FROM (
  SELECT prod,date,prod+';'+CAST(price AS varchar(8))+';'
        +replace(CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102),'.','') csv
  FROM prodtbl
  UNION ALL
  SELECT null,'1/1/1900',@header
 ) csvexp ORDER BY prod,date
END
```

The command

```
EXEC csvexp 'my very own csv export'
```

will then generate the following output:

```
my very own csv export
product1;150;20150727
product2;180;20150727
product3;180;20150727
```

The part of actually getting this output into a `.csv` file still remains to be done ...

Comment: Thanks cars10 for the response, but it will not help as it will show the output as above. Its showing me only last column and header.